# How to remove cache after a new build react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser-cache

When we have a new build in our react project, users who work with our PWA because they have old cache they cant have our last changes and they have to remove their cache by press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to reload again and then our changes work so we try to find the best solution to solve the problem.

I want to remove the cache for all users after the new build from the react projects.

Comment: This is well documented, it always requires a refresh. That's why apps like Soundcloud and Codesandbox say "There's been an update, click this button to refresh". You can detect an update and prompt them to refresh or have a button to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I solved this problem for my projects.
I define a variable in local storage for versioning and I saved the project version after build and checked the version in the first react file ( `componentDidMount()` in `Routes.js` for example ) if they didn't match run the code below :

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

example :

```
    componentDidMount(){
        let name = 'Project-Name'
        let version = '1.0.0'
        console.log(`${name} v${version} `)
        const last_version = localStorage.getItem(`${name}-Version`)
        if(last_version !== version){
            console.log('New Version Available ! ')
            localStorage.setItem(`${name}-Version`, version)
            window.location.reload(true);
        }
    }
```